# mail not send through workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am creating a work flow that send the mail manually on a document in document library.

I am follows the steps at

> http://www.documentmanagementworkflowinfo.com/sample-sharepoint-workflows/sharepoint-designer-workflow-allow-users-enter-email-address-before-running-workflow.htm

but when the workflow run from sharepoint it runs well there but mail not send to the recipient.

What is the problem? Is there is any SMTP require or any other issue?

Regards,
Girish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to verify the outbound SMTP server is setup correctly in Central Administration > Operations.  If the server has been configured for SMTP, you can use localhost.  If not, you'll need to find an email relay server that has been configured to send out emails.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this blog: http://mosshowto.blogspot.com/2010/05/installing-smtp-pop3-sharepoint-2010.html

This worked for me.